# How do I load Twig files from s3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, twig, cdn

Trying to load twig template files from s3:

```
$themePath = "https://path/to/s3/file";
require_once APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($themePath);

$this->appTwig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
//   'cache' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/../cache',
));
$this->view->appTwig = $this->appTwig;

$this->template = $this->appTwig->loadTemplate($this->appView.'.yo');
echo $this->template->render(array();
```

When I try to load a template file, I get an exception that says "directory does not exist".

Basically I want to store all the twig files on s3 so they are accessible from any of my servers. Have no clue how to make this work. It looks like Twig requires there to be a directory on a local machine as the file system. please help!!!

Comment: Doesn't Symfony2 compile the Twig templates and cache the results anyway? If it works how I think it does, I don't see the benefit of this. Ideally you're Twig templates are only used when rebuilding the cache, so you aren't really getting a benefit of a CDN

Comment: The benefit is that the files can be stored (and edited) in a central location and then "served" out.I actually wound up using file_get_contents to the file on s3 and then loading the twig template from a string with $twig = new Twig_Environment(new Twig_Loader_String()); and using ACE editor to edit the files directly on s3

Comment: Okay, but when you say they are "served" out, do you mean the *.twig files are directly served? That wouldn't make sense because you don't technically want your twig files accessible over HTTP (which is why they are not in the web root by default). Or you just mean they are served to multiple load balanced servers with your Sf2 application and those servers update their caches appropriately? How do you trigger a cache update on your server when you change the Twig file?

Comment: I have the twig files in s3. my app grabs the contents of the twig file (over http) and then creates a twig environment from the string. I'm actually using Zend application instead of SF2, so I only grab the contents of the files on s3 when the cache has expired or the twig file has been updated (from an editor I have built in to the app). This way users can author their own "apps" with twig that run inside my application by creating twig files that then are passed data by my application. Since the files are in s3, I can set a bucket policy that only my servers can access them.

Comment: What is the harm of having twig files accessible over http?

Comment: By default, twig files are outside of the web root. In theory you could inadvertently reveal details about your application logic in your twig files (just like in any of your other .php files, except they will be served as plain text). It's not a big risk as long as your config files with passwords are not accessible. I feel like there's a bigger risk of letting users edit twig files (cross-site scripting and other injections). But I'm sure this depends on a number of factors. Something to be aware of, however. Good luck